# Replace "\n" in element string with <br> tag in Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, tags, beautifulsoup, newline

I am creating a new tag and assigning a string with a newline

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup("", "html.parser")

myTag = soup.new_tag("div")
myTag.string = "My text \n with a new line"

soup.insert(0, myTag)
```

and the result is

```
<div>My text 
 with a new line</div>
```

as expected. However the newlines need the `<br>` tag in order to be rendered correctly.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `myTag.string = "My text \n with a new line".replace('\n','<br />')`

Comment: You could set `style='white-space:pre-wrap'` on the div -  see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it might be better to set the CSS [white-space](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp) property to `pre-wrap` on that div:

> **pre-wrap** --   Whitespace is preserved by the browser. Text will wrap when necessary, and on line breaks.

An example:

```
<div style="white-space:pre-wrap"> Some \n text here </div>
```

And the code to do that in BeautifulSoup:

```
myTag = soup.new_tag("div", style="white-space:pre-wrap")
myTag.string = "My text \n with a new line"
```

Seems that replacing the `\n` is not trivial since BeautifulSoup will escape the HTML entities by default. An alternative is to split the input string and build up the tag structure with text and `<br>` tags on your own:

```
def replace_newline_with_br(s, soup):
    lines = s.split('\n')
    div = soup.new_tag('div')
    div.append(lines[0])
    for l in lines[1:]:
        div.append(soup.new_tag('br'))
        div.append(l)
    soup.append(div)

mytext = "My text with a few \n newlines \n"
mytext2 = "Some other text \n with a few more \n newlines \n here"

soup = BeautifulSoup("", )
replace_newline_with_br(mytext, soup)
replace_newline_with_br(mytext2, soup)
print soup.prettify()
```

Prints:

```
<div>
 My text with a few
 <br/>
 newlines
 <br/>
</div>
<div>
 Some other text
 <br/>
 with a few more
 <br/>
 newlines
 <br/>
 here
</div>
```

Comment: The replace method doesn't work, Beautifulsoup just escapes the tags.

Comment: You are right. Do you need an alternate solution or is the CSS based one sufficient?

Comment: Setting `pre-wrap` introduces other problems, because Beautifulsoup rearranges whitespaces when prettifying and writing to a file. I would rather achieve the effect with `<br>` tags